# Help needed on web spider

Tags: java, html, browser, web-scraping

I am writing a very basic web spider in java.I am facing one problem, that content loaded for same url is different than that in browser.For example try below URL.

[http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web+spider#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=web+spider&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=web+spider&pbx=1&fp=d8e8e41d6d2bda33&biw=1366&bih=643](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web%20spider#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=web%20spider&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=web%20spider&pbx=1&fp=d8e8e41d6d2bda33&biw=1366&bih=643)

If you load this url in browser, and through JAVA URL class, the contents are different.This may be because of the following reasons.

- Javascript may be sending
  XMLHTTPrequests and concatenating the
  result to render final HTML.
- URL redirects may finally render the
  HTML.
- Any other reasons, that I dont know.

So is there a way that I simulate browser in my java program.Are There any third party libraries, that loads the page similar to what browser does and finally return the content.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried including USER_AGENT in java to match your web browser?

Comment: Ya..I included user_agent same as IE8, but same problem. This is because browser executes javascripts which may send XMLHTTPRequest and concatenate the result to form final content.So is there a way to simulate simulate browsers and get the final content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) it can emulate browser behaviour and handle javascript